# Air Pressure and Ball Valves

Tags: valve, air-compressor

I'm making my own airsoft gun and I need a pressure regulator for my HPA tank. It outputs 800 PSI which I need to bring down to about 130 PSI. Problem is, air pressure regulators that support 800 PSI cost around $120. I don't have the money for this, so I'm wondering if it'd be possible to use a ball valve that's almost completely closed to reduce the pressure. I found one that supports up to 1000 PSI on Amazon for around $7.

Comment: I don’t know who down voted but it is a good question. Please leave a reason for a downvote. There are a few of us that will change a downvote if no reason is given and although the OP’s plan could have been very dangerous it was good that the question was asked.

Comment: @EdBeal  I voted to close because it's not home improvement but did not dv question. I've never dv'd... I just comment to correct.

Comment: Agreed VTC I hope the op understands the difference between a valve and a regulator now.

Comment: Being cheap with dangerous things can cost you more than money.

Answer (score 5):

NO , a ball valve only will control flow. If you even allow a slight orifice the size of a human hair with time the chamber pressure would be at 800 psi.

I would look for a used scuba regulator they can handle up to 3000 psi and the first stage around 135psi , their actual output pressure can be adjusted a little. 
I mention this because I used an old scuba regulator to charge my potato guns. 
Other possible regulators C02  I think they are 1200psi with the output being adjustable, oxygen or acetylene regs, 
Try Craig’s list or eBay for used regs possibly from a welding shop call and ask. 
There are lots of options that will be much safer.

Do not use a valve you need some kind of regulator.

Comment: I would have any “old regulator” checked and serviced before use: this is dangerous advice because regulators could fail in an ‘open’ state giving the same result as a valve, complete release of pressure. All it takes is a bad or very old o-ring. I was given this advice by the man who serviced my scuba regulators for years and taught our rescue courses for DAN. He is retired now, but was certified by all of the brands he serviced, including ScubaPro. Please don’t give dangerous advice!

Comment: @old uncle ho, an an retired instructor trainer for several agency’s and certified service tech for many brands (I owned Corvallis scuba academy and ran it with up to 8 instructors) first stage regulator is a good choice I even have old 2 hose regulators from the 60’s that still work so you can say whatever you like a scuba reg is a good choice as there operational range is limited any reg new or old in this case should have a pressure gauge as even an air soft gun could be lethal.

Comment: A bad regulator could be dangerous, in short. Take care

Comment: @JACK a broken, free flowing regulator is no better than a ball-valve. I cited my reference because this can be an unnecessarily tough crowd, and advising use of an unchecked regulator is dangerous advice.